# Future of Iterable to run sequentially

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

Code with explanation:

```scala
val partitions = preparePartitioningDataset(dataset, "sdp_id").map { partitions =>
  val resultPartitionedDataset: Iterator[Future[Iterable[String]]] = for {
    partition <- partitions
  } yield {
    val whereStatement = s"SDP_ID = '$partition'"
    val partitionedDataset =
      datasetService.getFullDatasetResultIterable(
        dataset = dataset,
        format = format._1,
        limit = none[Int],
        where = whereStatement.some
      )
    partitionedDataset
  }
  
  resultPartitionedDataset
}

partitions.map { partitionedDataset =>
  for {
    partition <- partitionedDataset
  } notifyPartitionedDataset(
    bearerToken = bearerToken,
    endpoint = endpoint,
    dataset = partition
  )
}
```

So now

- `preparePartitioningDataset(dataset, "sdp_id")` returns a `Future[Iterator[String]]`
- `datasetService.getFullDatasetResultIterable` returns itself also a `Future[Iterable[String]]`
- Pretty much you see that `resultPartitionedDataset` is an `Iterator[Future[Iterable[String]]]`
- and Finally `notifyPartitionedDataset` returns a `Future[Unit]`

About some explanation of what's happening and what I'm trying to achieve

I have `preparePartioningDataset` that performs a `Select Distinct` on a single value, giving back a Future[ResultSet] (mapped to an Iterator). This because for each single value I want to perform a `SELECT * WHERE column=that_value`. This happens on `getFullDatasetResultIterable`, again a Future[ResultSet] mappet to an Iterator as well.

Last step is to forward via a POST, every single query I got.
It works, but everything happens in parallel (well I guess that's why I wanted to go for a Future), but now I got required that each POST (`notifyPartionedDataset`) happens sequentially, so to send a post after another and not in parallel.

I've tried a lot of different approaches but I still get the same outcome.

How could I move forward?

Comment: A `Future[Iterator]` doesn't make much sense, to be honest, you may rather use some streaming library like **AkkaStreams** or just use a concrete collection. You may also use `Future.traverse` with a single-threaded EC to do the notify or write your own version that does it independently of the EC. - I personally would just drop `Future` in favor of `IO` which would allow controlling this situation quite easily; and I would also use **fs2**. - Finally, a style recommendation, don't write single line `fors`

Comment: I've moved from Future.traverse to Future[Iterator] because I had exactly same issue, this is like my forth/fifth version trying to solve this issue but with not succeed :(

Comment: Yeah, you are being bitted by the eagerness of `Future` you may solve the problem using custom `EC` or again just use `IO` is not that different and will solve this problem out of the box. Check: https://github.com/Daenyth/intro-cats-effect

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the laziness of the `IO` datatype to ensure that some operations are executed in order.

```scala
import cats.effect.IO

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def preparePartitioningDatasetIO(dataset: String, foo: String): IO[List[String]] =
  IO.fromFuture(IO(
    preparePartitioningDataset(dataset, foo))
  )).map(_.toList)

def getFullDatasetResultIterableIO(dataset: String, format: String, limit: Option[Int], where: Option[String]): IO[List[String]] =
  IO.fromFuture(IO(
    datasetService.getFullDatasetResultIterable(
      dataset,
      format,
      limit,
      where
    )
  ))
  
def notifyPartitionedDatasetIO(bearerToken: String, endpoint: String, dataset: List[String]): IO[Unit] =
  IO.fromFuture(IO(
    notifyPartitionedDataset(
      bearerToken,
      endpoint,
      dataset
    )
  ))
  
def program(dataset: String): IO[Unit] =
  preparePartitioningDatasetIO(dataset, "sdp_id").flatMap { partitions =>
    partitions.traverse_ { partition =>
      val whereStatement = s"SDP_ID = '$partition'"
      getFullDatasetResultIterableIO(
        dataset = dataset,
        format = format._1,
        limit = none,
        where = whereStatement.some
      ).flatMap { dataset =>
        notifyPartitionedDatasetIO(
          bearerToken = bearerToken,
          endpoint = endpoint,
          dataset = dataset
        )
      }
    }
  }


def run(dataset: String): Future[Unit] = {
  import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
  program(dataset).unsafeToFuture()
}
```

The code needs to be carefully reviewed and fixed, especially the arguments of the functions.
But, this should help to get the result you want without needing to refactor the whole codebase; yet.

---

If you want `getFullDatasetResultIterableIO` to run in parallel while `notifyPartitionedDatasetIO` to run serially you can do this:

```scala
def program(dataset: String): IO[Unit] =
  preparePartitioningDatasetIO(dataset, "sdp_id").flatMap { partitions =>
    partitions.parTraverse { partition =>
      val whereStatement = s"SDP_ID = '$partition'"
      getFullDatasetResultIterableIO(
        dataset = dataset,
        format = format._1,
        limit = none,
        where = whereStatement.some
      )
    } flatMap { datasets =>
      datasets.traverse_ { dataset =>
        notifyPartitionedDatasetIO(
          bearerToken = bearerToken,
          endpoint = endpoint,
          dataset = dataset
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

Although this would imply that the whole data is kept in memory before starting to notify.